# Why doesn't Bruce Nolan literally turn into Clint Eastwood?

Tags: clint-eastwood, bruce-almighty

In *Bruce Almighty*, shortly after being endowed with all of God's powers, Bruce says, "If that was God, then I'm Clint Eastwood."

Bruce then takes on the mannerisms of Clint and his back windshield is destroyed by gunfire. However, Bruce doesn't literally become the famous actor. (Of course, the movie doesn't distinguish between a character Eastwood has played and the actor himself, but maybe I'm splitting hairs.)

The real-world reason is probably due to cost considerations or perhaps not wanting to actually use Clint Eastwood's image. But is there a valid in-universe reason?

Comment: Also, Jim Carey does a pretty good Clint Eastwood.

Answer (score 2):

1. It'd be a waste to ignore [Jim Carrey's impersonation talent](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V51KvcaA5c0).
2. It'd be more jarring for the actor to change mid-scene, without provocation or buildup. While the joke remains the same, having the real Clint Eastwood site there for a short is more jarring and is more likely going to take the viewer outside of their suspense of disbelief.
3. Having Jim impersonate Clint means that it's a gradual decline. Viewers who don't expect this to happen will not notice this until a few seconds in, which can make it funnier.

If your question is intended as a suggestion for us to confirm that your idea (doing it differently than the movie did) would be better, this is off-topic and against [the rules](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask):

> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …
>
> - there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”
> - you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”

Comment: All 3 of your reasons are out-of-universe explanations; while the question is asking for an in-universe explanation.

Comment: Um, no, I'm asking why Bruce Nolan didn't literally turn into Clint Eastwood.

Comment: @GendoIkari: The expectation of an in-universe justification does not prove the the existence of one. It's very common, especially for comedy movies, for the in-universe events to exist purely to make the (out of universe) viewer laugh as opposed to focusing on realism.